# How to parcelise member variable other than constructor in data class while using @Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using Room and Kotlin data class. Such as,

```
@Entity(tableName = "Person")
@Parcelize
class Test(@ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name:String) : Parcelable{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

I can create the instance using the constructor and insert the data. I am also getting a warning `"property would not be serialized into a 'parcel'"`. When I was trying to send the object through a bundle, the id is missing, which is expected as the warning says so. How can I add that member `ID` in the parcel? I am not keeping the ID in the constructor as I want them to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find this information with the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize):

> `@Parcelize` requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. Android Extensions will issue a warning on each property with a backing field declared in the class body. Also, `@Parcelize` can't be applied if some of the primary constructor parameters are not properties.
>
> If your class requires more advanced serialization logic, you can write it inside a companion class:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int) : Parcelable {
    private companion object : Parceler<User> {
        override fun User.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            // Custom write implementation
        }

        override fun create(parcel: Parcel): User {
            // Custom read implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New link for the docs - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#parcelable-implementations-generator

Comment: new link https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize