# How @Ignore works in data class with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I was trying to make a dataclass for Room and the class also have a field which is for the views only. I do not want to save the data into Room.

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyTable")
@Parcelize
data class MyTable(
    @SerializedName("id") @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @SerializedName("field1") val field1: String?,
    var selected: Boolean? = false //todo use @Ignore
) : Parcelable
```

The above code works. However whenever I tried to use `@Ignore` annotation with the variable with `selected` variable. Its giving me the following error

```
error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

If I remove the variable from the constructor like

```
    @Entity(tableName = "MyTable")
    @Parcelize
    data class MyTable(
        @SerializedName("id") @PrimaryKey val id: String,
        @SerializedName("field1") val field1: String?

    ) : Parcelable{
    var selected: Boolean? = false //todo use @Ignore
    }
```

The field `selected` will not be written into the parcel. How can I keep the variable into the class without making a column and still keeping it into the parcel?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can just have an empty constructor. Do you get any error with that?

Comment: I tried with empty constructor. still its not working. I also used @ignore with the constructor. but didnt work

Comment: @Parcelize requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. So I think you have to implement your on custom parcelisation. I hope this answer ca give you more clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312247/how-to-parcelise-member-variable-other-than-constructor-in-data-class-while-usin

Comment: did you trying using without data class and just normal class?

Answer (score 4):

`@Ignore` in such a case currently [requires](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70762008) `@JvmOverloads` annotation:

```
data class MyTable @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ...
    @Ignore var selected: Boolean? = false
)
```

Comment: It's not working. 
`error: Room cannot pick a constructor since multiple constructors are suitable. Try to annotate unwanted constructors with @Ignore.`

Comment: There were issues with KSP (see thread linked in the answer), but they seem to be resolved (tested with Room 2.6.1 & KSP 1.9.0-1.0.13). The error might be caused by [Room/Kotlin version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76897431), or by specifics of your entity (can you share it?).