# Why do I get so many errors about Room when I upgrade Kotlin from 1.8.10 to 1.9.0 in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-room

The Code A and Code B work well in my Android Studio project when I use *Kotlin 1.8.10 (with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.4.2)* and *Room 2.5.1*.

After I upgrade Kotlin from *1.8.10 (with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.4.2)*
to *1.9.0 (with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.1')*, I get the Error A and the Error B when I try to compile the project.

The Error A is fixed when I replace the Code A with Code AA.

How can I fix the Error B ?

BTW, the Code C is the generated automatically by Android Studio for the Code B.

And more, the Code A and Code B work well when I upgrade Kotlin from *1.8.10 (with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.4.2)*
to *1.8.22 (with kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.8')*.

**Code A**

```
@Entity(tableName = "info_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class RecordEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
     var text:     String = "", 
         ...
)
```

**Code B**

```
@Dao
interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where id=:id")
    suspend fun getByID(id:Int): RecordEntity    
    ...
}
```

**Error A**

```
There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors. public final class RecordEntity {
```

**Error B**

```
Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).    public abstract java.lang.Object getByID(int id, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
Unused parameter: $completion    public abstract java.lang.Object getByID(int id, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
```

**Code AA**

```
@Entity(tableName = "info_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class  RecordEntity(
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
     var text:    String = "",  
       ...
) {
    @Ignore
     constructor() : this(0)
}
```

**Code C -- Generated automatically by Android Studio**

```
@androidx.room.Query(value = "SELECT * FROM info_table where id=:id")
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
public abstract java.lang.Object getByID(int id, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.hicalc.soundrecorder.data.database.RecordEntity> $completion);
```

Comment: Usually update with ```kotlin```, ```android gradle plugin``` and some others key tools go with each other. Please pay attention to them and double check ```kotlin 1.9.0``` press release and docs for breaking changes.

Comment: Is Error A actually an error, or just a warning or info message?

Comment: This reads more like a rant than a question. If you need help fixing specific errors, you can ask a question about only that.

Comment: To Tenfour04: Thanks! The Error A actually is an error, and the Code AA can fix it

Comment: @HelloCW when you update the Kotlin version, you may need to upgrade the room version as well, see docs for compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Room needs to update its `kotlinx-metadata-jvm` dependency to be able to read Kotlin 1.9+ metadata. Dependency update should come with Room `2.5.3`.

For reference see last comments here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236612358

Same thing happened with previous kotlin updates as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mean I have to wait for  Room 2.5.3 in order to fix the bugs?

Comment: Yes, you need to wait for Room 2.5.3 before you can update kotlin to 1.9+. Alternatively you could try with Room 2.6.0-alpha03 which should work with kotlin 1.9+. Just wouldn't recommend if you plan a production release with that

Answer (score 4):

You can also solve the problem by changing to `KSP` from `KAPT` while Room support is still in progress for Kotlin `1.9+`
Also, it's recommended to migrate to KSP if your libraries support KSP. You will not face this kind of problem if you migrate to KSP and also it's faster than KAPT.
See [here](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp?authuser=1) for migration steps.

Comment: Room only supports KSP from `2.6.0` on (or currently `2.6.0-alpha03`). And that version works with kotlin `1.9+` anyway, no matter if KSP or KAPT.

Comment: No, I think room supports KSP from **2.3.0-beta02** so it can be used with 2.5.0 as well as OP required.  See below for reference https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-beta02

Comment: Oh you are right, my bad than. Wonder why they didn't include that in the 2.3.0 stable release notes...