# Property would not be serialized into a 'Parcel'. Add '@IgnoredOnParcel' annotation to remove the warning

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, companion-object

Hey I am working in android Kotlin. I am getting this weird warning

```
Property would not be serialized into a 'Parcel'. Add '@IgnoredOnParcel' annotation to remove the warning
```

I don't want to add **@IgnoredOnParcel** this annotation in my class. I want to handle in proper way. I used this [How to parcelise member variable other than constructor in data class while using @Parcelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53314594) to put my member inside the **companion object**. I did this correctly but the problem is I cannot access the variable of my data class. Can someone guide me how to get access of my data class variable. Thanks

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class XYZ(
    val value: String? = null,
) : Parcelable {
    companion object {
        var valueInDouble: Double
            get() {
                return value?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: Double.NaN
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Getting error on my **value** variable when I am accessing in my **companion object**

```
Unresolved reference: value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the companion object and use val:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class XYZ(
    val value: String? = null,
) : Parcelable {
        val valueInDouble: Double
            get() {
                return value?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: Double.NaN
            }
}
```